# Resolution issue in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, display-resolution

A few months back I installed 12.04 on a separate hard drive just to keep track of developments. during that time I noticed that the resolution was not great, everything seemed just a little blurry. Not by huge amounts but just enough to notice it especially after switching from my main 11.10 install.

I didn't take a lot of notice as 12.04 was still in its development stage, however now that I have upgraded my primary hard drive to 12.04 final I now have the issue permanently.

My graphics card is an Nvidia GeForce 9300 GE. I have tried both drivers available to me (no change)

Something that does work however is if I change the refresh rate via Nvidia settings. It defaults to 75Hz which I can change to auto or 60Hz, if I make the change to either of those the problem is solved. Even though I am saving the settings to /etc/X11/xorg.conf if I log out or reboot it defaults back to 75Hz.
How can I make this change permanent or should I be looking at changing something else?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was later resolved with updates to the Nvidia driver. After the update the change I made to the refresh rate then became permanent.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the DPI settings as well to ensure that they match the monitor. The wrong setting would give it a flattened look that may also appear fuzzy.

Comment: DPI is showing as 95x96. My monitor does not give a recommendation for this so I am not sure if that is good or bad.

Comment: Chris, this is a common dpi setting for a number of monitors. Another common one is 72 dpi. I should note that when using the nvidia-settings tool, you might need to run it as higher permissioned user, for example, starting the nvidia-settings manager in terminal like this could save the settings permanently: sudo nvidia-settings